# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString isFileURL]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, imageview

I have an array of url:

```
imageurl =  

   (
        "http://10.1.1.4:8084/Photos/AA/c6aee8617ec94116911e17f745ced4d8.jpg",
        "http://10.1.1.4:8084/Photos/AA/75764b74fbc440c790ff235e5336223e.jpg",
        "http://10.1.1.4:8084/Photos/AA/4b390e733d8c48a6931079120af60b0a.jpg",
        "http://10.1.1.4:8084/Photos/AA/2fade8440ae74b4dabdaff5dc13c5128.jpg"
    );
```

I am trying to implement horizontal scroll view with images on url using the following code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    int pageCount=4;
    _scroller.pagingEnabled=YES;
    _scroller.contentSize=CGSizeMake(pageCount*_scroller.bounds.size.width,_scroller.bounds.size.height);
    CGRect ViewSize=_scroller.bounds;

    NSArray *imgArray = [self.tripDetails valueForKey:@"Flightimageurl"];


    for(int i=0;i<[imgArray count];i++)
    {

         UIImageView *imgView1=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:ViewSize];

        NSURL *url=[imgArray objectAtIndex:i];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];


        imgView1.image=[UIImage imageWithData:data];
        [_scroller addSubview:imgView1];
        [self.view addSubview:_scroller];
        ViewSize =CGRectOffset(ViewSize,_scroller.bounds.size.width,0);

    }
```

But this crashes and give the above exception. How this can be fixed and image from url can be shown on `imageView`.

Comment: `[imgArray objectAtIndex:i]` returns a `NSString`, not an `NSUrl`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting this crash because your `imgArray` contains `NSString` objects not `NSURL` objects, so first you need to create `NSURL` instance from that `NSString` instance.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[imgArray objectAtIndex:i]];
```